# How to use If operator in MS Solver Foundation?

Tags: c#, ms-solver-foundation

What's wrong with this code?:

```
SolverContext sc = SolverContext.GetContext();
Model m = sc.CreateModel();

m.AddDecision(new Decision(Domain.IntegerNonnegative, "a"));
m.AddDecision(new Decision(Domain.IntegerNonnegative, "b"));

m.AddConstraint(null, "a < 2");
m.AddConstraint(null, "b == If[a == 2, 2, 1]");

var sol = sc.Solve();
Console.WriteLine(sol.GetReport());
```

The solver freezes and doesn't give any result. I'm playing with the `If` operator trying to see how it works but doesn't seem to do what I expect. Not sure I'm using it the right way (I'm trying to say, if `a` equals `2` then `b` must equal `2`, otherwise `1`).

I also tried

```
m.AddConstraint(null, "If[a == 2, b == 2, b == 1]");
```

with the same result.

Comment: You might also try here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/solverfoundation/threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the solver that is applied to this problem is hampered by the extent of the `Decision` domain. If you limit the domain to for example the integer range [0, 10]:

```
m.AddDecision(new Decision(Domain.IntegerRange(0, 10), "a"));
m.AddDecision(new Decision(Domain.IntegerRange(0, 10), "b"));
```

a feasible solution to the problem is generated fairly quickly. In other words, the constraint `b == If[a == 2, 2, 1]` is perfectly valid.

BTW, it is a little odd that you in the first constraint require that `a < 2`, and in the second constraint test the condition `a == 2`. But I assume you are in an experimentation phase right now...